# Go return json variables without capitals

Tags: json, go

I'm a new user converting an application to Go. I have something like the following which is working:

```
type Network struct {
        Ssid     string
        Security string
        Bitrate  string
}

func Scan(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        output := runcmd(scripts+"scan.sh", true)
        bytes := []byte(output)
        var networks []Network
        json.Unmarshal(bytes, &networks)
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(networks)
}
```

The problem is the old version didn't use capitals on the json variables returned.

I want the front-end to see `ssid` not `Ssid`. If I make the attributes in the struct lowercase the code no longer works as they become unexported variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the field names in your struct do not match the json field names, you can use field tags.
eg:

```
Ssid string `json:"myOtherFieldName"`
```

Please read the [json docs](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

This tool very convenient for learning:

https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/

Give it example of JSON that you want it will recommend golang.

e.g. JSON

```
{
   "ssid": "some very long ssid",
   "security": "big secret",
   "bitrate": 1024
}
```

will suggest golang:

```golang
type AutoGenerated struct {
    Ssid     string `json:"ssid"`
    Security string `json:"security"`
    Bitrate  int    `json:"bitrate"`
}
```

now you can change `AutogGenerated, Ssid, Security, Bitrate` to whatever you want.